# Use case for making a parent point to child

Tags: java, inheritance

Given the following:

```
Dog rover = new Puppy("rover");  // Where Puppy extends Dog
```

A student asked why would you ever want or need a Dog object to point to a Puppy object? The only answer I could come up with is the following:

> Suppose we have a game program with Dogs and Puppies. A Puppy may have some special attributes and methods that a Dog does not have. Over the course of the game we may want our variable "rover" to be able to point to a Dog instead of a Puppy.

I'm comfortable with this answer but are there other kinds of use cases where having a Parent class point to a Child class  would be useful?

Comment: Please don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76149197/3001761).

Comment: can we chat?...

Comment: No, thank you. This kind of question might be on topic at https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Well on my point of View if Dog is an Abstract Class. Then we know that all dogs can bark, run, walk, jump. That is why is an Abstract Class. Now if Puppy extends to Dog. Then it can have all the defaults methods of the Abstract Class of Dog. But you can Override. Walk like a puppy, jump like a puppy. But you are still a Dog. So for example you have a pack of Dogs then you will have a List<Dogs> and each dog can be a puppy, adult dog and run different.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/7694), if you are going to post there can you delete here (also note your quote is *not* code, hence the formatting applied here).

Comment: I think the real thrust of a reason to "Why" is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (the "L" in SOLID!). Suppose you have some code that worked on `Puppy`, but later wanted to adopt it to `Wolf`. If your code worked on `Dog`, it would already then work for `Puppy` and `Wolf`.

Answer (score 0):

> why would you ever want or need a Dog object to point to a Puppy object?

While student failed to explain the main point (confusion), the question is absolutely reasonable.

Usually when you build domain model - it should reflect real-life types and objects. So `Dog` > `Puppy` hierarchy as an example is incomplete and thus looks weird.

However when you add more types **of the same level** as `Puppy`, e.g. `GrownDog`, then hierarchy becomes more meaningful and provides you with better examples. `GrownDog` can have offspring or can guard, `Puppy` can suck milk or can become a ball with paws (after a good feed) - these are distinct examples of **the same level** types.

After you have two or more types of the same level it becomes more clear why you may need to treat `GrownDog` and/or `Puppy` as just a `Dog` - for cases, when you don't care about specifics, but need some **common behaviour**. For example to implement `greetOwner(Dog)` by wagging and barking.

Answer (score -1):

A `Dog` object is not pointing to a `Puppy` object. A `Dog` object can only point to a `Dog` object, to which a `Puppy` is one. You cannot do

```java
Dog rover = new Kitten();
```

This will not compile because a `kitten` is not a dog, ever. But, a `puppy` is. You could do `Dog rover = new BullDog()` where all dogs have a method called `wagTail()`. But since bulldogs have stubby little tails, while they technical can wag their tails, they effectively don't have one.

Your explanation of polymorphism to your student is correct (as stated), but his question doesn't make sense